# Catch exceptions with IDataErrorInfo

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, exception

I want to validate the input of a TextBox. I used the IDataErrorInfo interface to do so. When the user input is bad the property ValueIsValid is set to false. However, I use the property InputValue for the TextInput (its an int). When the user types "1234" the IDataErrorInfo interface checks if the input is correct and sets if needed the ValueIsValid to false.
But when the user types "blabla" the input is not being converted to an int and IDataErrorInfo interface is not being called => ValueIsValid is not set to false.
How do I set ValueIsValid to false when the user types "blabla" in the TextBox?
I can't access the validation.hasError property of the TextBox from my viewmodel because I use MVVM.

ViewModel:

```cs
public class ViewModel : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public bool ValueIsValid { get; set; }

    public string StrErrorMessage
    {
        get { return "Some Error ..."; }
    }

    public int InputValue
    {
        get { return m_inputValue; }
        set
        {
            m_inputValue = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
            ValueIsValid = true;
        }
    }

    protected int m_inputValue;

    public string Error
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (columnName == "InputValue")
            {
                if (InputValue == 10)
                {
                    ValueIsValid = false;
                    return "Wrong value in TextBox.";
                }
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

WPF

```xml
<TextBox Text="{Binding InputValue, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding StrErrorMessage}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: How is "blabla" supposed to be converted to an `int`? You can't set an `int` property to anything else than a valid `int` value. And it's not the responsibility of the view model to perform this validation. It exposes an `int` property and it is up to the consumer of the class to set this property. The value "blabla" never reaches your view model. The conversion error is taking care of by the framework.

Comment: You are totally right. But I want that the ValueIsValid property will be set to false when a user enters "blabla" in the TextBox. In my code the TextBox turns red when you enter "blabla" but the ValueIsValid property still has the same value as before (true).

Comment: Why would you set the `ValueIsValid` property to false before the value property is set?

Comment: it can also be after. For example you type "1234" => ValueIsValid is set to true. Then you add "ab" so its "1234ab". Now ValueIsValid is not set back to false.

Comment: The thing is that the value is never set to "1234ab". It's still 1234 and thus valid as far as the view model is concerned.

Comment: Yes but I need the ValueIsValid property later to check if Text on the gui screen is valid or not.